# Run-time error 380: Could not set ControlSource property. Invalid property value for userform in Excel

Tags: textbox, listbox, zooming, excel-2013, userform

I've created a userform in Excel 2013 from an internet resource. When I hit Ctrl-m or double-click the cell, a user form will pop up zoombox where I can easily view my comments and type new comments.

The run-time error 380 in the title appears on this line of code (see below for full code):

```
Me.TextBox1.ControlSource = ActiveCell.Parent.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address
```

(Before I included the ListBox on the user form, I would receive runtime error 424 Object Required on this same line of code.)

**My Input:**
I've looked at various answers on the internet, but I don't understand how to fix this Run time error 380 b/c it appeared after I added the listbox, but it doesn't refer to the line of code for the listbox.

**EDIT:** 
Should I list the values in the list box as?:

```
With ListBox1
        .AddItem "8"
        .AddItem "10"
        .AddItem "12", etc.
End With
```

**End EDIT**

How the userform will look when finished:

[image: Pic of Zoombox user form after it is finished]

**Code and setup:**

1. The userform has a TextBox1, where the comments appear and can be edited; a ListBox1, which lists the font sizes the user can choose to use on the comment text; and a CommandButton1 to show the user form.
2. I only changed the properties for the TextBox. MultiLine is True and Word Wrap is True and ScrollBars are None.

I would appreciate help fixing this.

Here is the full code, which is located under the user form:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Me.TextBox1.Font.Size = ListBox1.Value
End Sub

> '~~~~~~

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Me.TextBox1.ControlSource = ActiveCell.Parent.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address

Me.ListBox1.List = Array(8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24)

End Sub

> '~~~~~~

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload ZoomForm
End Sub
```

Here is the code under the command button, which is in a Module1 of the spreadsheet:

```
Sub ShowZoom()
    ZoomForm.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: Here is the answer for anyone else who might need help. It was the quotes in the line of code that had the error.

```
Me.TextBox2.ControlSource = "'" & ActiveCell.Parent.Name & "'!" & ActiveCell.Address
```

The quotes are as follows: (single quote = sq, double quote = dq - with no spaces in between):

```
Me.TextBox2.ControlSource = (dq)(sq)(dq) & ActiveCell.Parent.Name & (dq)(sq)!(dq) & ActiveCell.Address
```

I found the answer here: [Forum used to help re: quotes](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=198414)

I don't know why the sample form with this code works with the code as I originally posted for this line, but it doesn't work in my workbook. I also changed the names of my userform and controls (textbox, listbox, etc.) to Textbox2, Listbox2, Commandbutton2, and ZoomForm2 just in case it was colliding with any code within the workbook, but I'm not sure that helped.

Here is the site where the code and sample form came from if you would like to add it to your spreadsheet:

[ZoomForm Site](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/creating-a-zoom-box-in-excel/)

Thank you.